# Error de "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" en ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, map

cómo va? Los molesto con un inconveniente que estoy teniendo con un proyecto en ReactJs.

Me figura el error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'.

Mi código es éste:

```
import { Component } from "react";

const styles = { 
    DetallesCarro:{
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        position: 'absolute',
        marginTop: 30,
        boxShadow: '1px 5px 5px rgb(0,0,0,0.3)',
        borderRadius:'5px',
        width:'300px',
        right:50,
    }
}

class DetallesCarro extends Component {
    render(){
        const { carro } = this.props
        console.log(carro)
        return (
            <div style={styles.DetallesCarro}>
                <ul>
                   {carro.map(x =>
                    <li key={x.name}>{x.name}</li>
                   )}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DetallesCarro
```

Desde ya, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: En el console.log te imprime algo??

Comment: Hay que verificar si se esta enviando el tipo correcto `carro` desde el componente padre de `DetallesCarro` via `props`. ¿Puedes agregar el componente padre?

Comment: Si pudieran agregar la respuesta anterior como comentario, ya no aparece, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que no esté llegando el array de carro o que inicie en undefined
Prueba con `carro?.map(...)` para evitar este tipo de errores o inicia el estado como un array vacío

```
this.state = {
   carro: []
}
```